# How to read data in one zip file located in another zipfile using ZipEntry?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, zip

I have a zip file (x.zip) in which there is another zipfile (y.zip). I need to read a file in y.zip. How can I iterate through both the zip files to read the file?

The code I am using to iterate x.zip to read y.zip is as below.

In the code, "zipX" represents "x.zip". When "y.zip" is encountered, it satisfies the "if condition" in the code. Here I need to iterate through "zipEntry" and read a file in that.

How can this be achieved?

```
private void getFileAsBytes(String path, String name) throws IOException {
        ZipFile zipX = new ZipFile(path);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipX.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements())
        {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
            if(zipEntry.getName().contains(name) && zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
                InputStream is;
                is = zipX.getInputStream(zipEntry);
                // Need to iterate through zipEntry here and read data from a file inside it.
                break;
            }
        }
        zipX.close();
}
```

Comment: how about using recursive approach till end??

Comment: Wrap the inner `InputStream` in a [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and read as normal zip "file"...

Comment: @MadProgrammer what if Y.zip has another zip file inside it? he needs to keep continuing with if/else block..

Comment: @Vikram Yeah...but what other choice do they have.  I'd write the method in recursive manner, so they could continue calling until they get to the bottom of the mess...

Comment: I suspect it's not possible, short of reconstituting the inner zip as a "real" file.  The zip code needs to "randomly" address the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ZipFile docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html), you need to pass in a File object or a file path; an InputStream isn't supported.

With that in mind, you could write that InputStream to a temporary file and then pass that file in to your existing method:

```
...
is = zipX.getInputStream(zipEntry);
File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
//For production, generate a unique name for the temp file instead of using "temp"!
File tempFile = createTempFile("temp", "zip", tmpDir);
this.getFileAsBytes(tempFile.getPath(), name);
break;
...
```